# Can't list table from SQL to MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my repository:

```
namespace Repositories
{
    public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
    {
        AppContext myDB = new AppContext();
        public List<Author> GetAllFromRepo()
        {
           return myDB.Authors.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My service file:

```
namespace Services
{
    public class AuthorService : IAuthorService
    {
        private readonly IAuthorRepository _AuthorRepository;

        public AuthorService(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
        {
            _AuthorRepository = authorRepository;
        }
        public List<AuthorViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            List<Author> authors = _AuthorRepository.GetAllFromRepo();

            return authors.Select( x => new AuthorViewModel()
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                FullName = $"{x.FirstName } {x.LastName} ",
                Books = x.Books.Select(g => new BookViewModel()
                {
                    ID = g.ID,
                    Name = g.Name
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My Author View Model:

```
    namespace ViewModels
{
    public class AuthorViewModel
    {
        public AuthorViewModel()
        {
            Books = new List<BookViewModel>();  
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string  FullName { get; set; }

        public List<BookViewModel> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Books View Model:

```
    namespace ViewModels
{
    public class BookViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AuthorViewModel Author { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IAuthorService _AuthorService;
    // GET: Home

    public HomeController(IAuthorService authorService)
    {
        _AuthorService = authorService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<AuthorViewModel> Authors = _AuthorService.GetAll();
        ViewBag.myAuthors = Authors;
        return View();

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Books(int id)
    {
        List<AuthorViewModel> Authors = _AuthorService.GetAll();


        ViewBag.Books = from a in Authors
                    where a.ID == id
                    select a.Books;

        return View();
    }
}
```

The index contorller work fine. But when I call the Books controller it gives me this error in my browser:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'ID'

Source error:

```
Line 18:     {
Line 19:         <tr>
Line 20:             <td>@book.ID</td>   // this is the error line
Line 21:             <td>@book.Name</td>
Line 22:             <td><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></td>
```

> Source File: C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\WebApp ver 1.2\WebApp\Views\Home\Books.cshtml    Line: 20

The View Model for Books:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Books";
}

<h2>Books</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var book in ViewBag.Books)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@book.ID</td>   
            <td>@book.ID</td>
            <td><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here in the Index View Model everything works fine:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<h2>Author List</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>FullName</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Books</th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var author in ViewBag.myAuthors)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@author.ID</td>
        <td>@author.FullName</td>
        <td><a href="~/Home/Meh/@author.ID">Details</a></td>
        <td><a href="~/Home/Books/@author.ID">Books</a></td>

    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Any guidence and help why I can't list the books in the view would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't show your View code in the question. Also, don't use ViewBag. It's MVC for a reason - learn to use the model.

Comment: show more code form your view please

Comment: Are you looping over `ViewBag.Books`?

Comment: Yes. I Will post the View model now

Comment: You do not need to use the Repository Anti-Pattern with Entity Framework, and you aren't disposing of your `DbContext` so you'll leak connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing List of authors as ViewBag.Books. The query which you are using in `Books` action will store list of Authors with only one column 'Books' in viewbag, so you do not have ID column in the ViewBag.Books.
you should modify the query as below.

```
ViewBag.Books = (from a in Authors
                    where a.ID == id select a).FirstOrDefault().Books;
```

Comment: Error CS0742 A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Comment: Thanks for the query, however it is not the only problem cause the ViewBag.Books is empty.

Comment: The service and repositories in your code seems to be incorrect. The repository method `GetAllFromRepo` is returning only authors without child collection of books. That's the root cause for not getting any data for books.  You should have another repository method to return books by author id, and then call the new repository method in `GetAll` method of service to load child collection for each author..

Comment: Ok and thanks for your time. This will help me a lot i hope.

Comment: Or you may try eager loading in `GetAllFromRep` by using Include method. Something like `return myDB.Authors.Include(a=>a.Books).ToList();` . It depends on how you have setup AppContext.

Comment: i tried this and i get error under (a=>a.Books), saying cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because is not a delegate type

Comment: adding  using System.Data.Entity; solved the error. Thanks man for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is that in your select you are picking a.Books i.e. list of books

```
ViewBag.Books = from a in Authors
                    where a.ID == id
                    select a.Books; //Here you select books, so you'll get a list of List<Books>
```

You should change your cshtml:

```
@foreach (var books in ViewBag.Books)
{
   @foreach (var book in books ){
    <tr>
        <td>@book.ID</td>   
        <td>@book.ID</td>
        <td><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></td>

    </tr>
   }
}
```

Or change your select.

In any case, you should not use Viewbag in this scenario, you define your Model in the view and pass it with the controller like MVC should act like.

Comment: Setting aside the Viewbag for now, the solution that you gave me doesn't list anything. No error, just empty table.

Comment: You are sure that there is data? Can you check with debug the context of your Viewbag.Books?

Comment: You are right, no data... I checked with the debug and it says, ViewBag.Books Count = 0; Can you point out where my problem could be.