# Deserialize json string using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I am working on deserialize json string using JavaScriptSerializer in C#, and trying to parse the json string and map it to the appropriate columns in the sql server table for inserting data. I have the sample json string as below.

#### JSON

```
{
    "event": [
        [
            {
                "Id": 456895,
                "Name": "Chelsea - Arsenal",
                "BetOffers": [
                    {
                        "BetType": "Game",
                        "Picks": [
                            {
                                "Pick": "1",
                                "Odds": 1.15
                            },
                            {
                                "Pick": "x",
                                "Odds": 1.46
                            },
                            {
                                "Pick": "2",
                                "Odds": 1.15
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Id": 456879,
                "Name": "Liverpool - Manchester United",
                "BetOffers": [
                    {
                        "BetType": "Game",
                        "Picks": [
                            {
                                "Pick": "1",
                                "Odds": 1.20
                            },
                            {
                                "Pick": "x",
                                "Odds": 1.42
                            },
                            {
                                "Pick": "2",
                                "Odds": 1.85
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Based on the json output string I am writing my class in C# as below.

#### Classes

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BetOffer> BetOffers { get; set; }
}

public class BetOffer
{
    public string BetType { get; set; }
    public List<BetPick> Picks { get; set; }
}

public class BetPick
{
    public string Pick { get; set; }
    public double Odds { get; set; }
}

public class MyRootObject
{
    public List<List<BetPick>> @event { get; set; }
}
    
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyRootObject>(jsonString);
```

Insert data into the table as following.

```
string connectionString = "Database ConnectionString";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BetType", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Pick", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Odds", typeof(string)));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

for (var i = 0; i < root.event.Count; i++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = root.event[i].Id;//stuck at table to json string parse and map
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

#### Question

I'm stuck with how to parse json string and map data to appropriate columns in the table for inserting data into a sql table. Unable to find root.event.Id from the json string?

#### Error

List does not contain definition for Id

Comment: Why are we using `JavaScriptSerializer` again? Although likely not the problem here. I would suggest using Json.Net or Text.Json

Comment: @TheGeneral, I have constraints using Newtonsoft Json.

Comment: I recommend clarifying the question.   The title specifically states deserialization, but you have database stuff in the question.  So what's *not* working, needs to be the question.

Comment: Even reading it with JavaScript and saving it back in format you like would likely be easier... Getting free advice on such an old piece of code could be hard...

Comment: @ErikPhilips, when I try to parse Id (root.event.Id) from the json string I get the error List does not contain definition for Id.

Comment: Your root object is 'List<List<BetPick>>' which ultimately is a list which does not contain a definition for Id. Try making your root object something that has an Id per row. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140749/cant-list-table-from-sql-to-mvc-view as well. It might help.

Comment: `root.event` **cannot** have an `Id` property because it is a list. Did you mean `root.event[0].Id` ?

Comment: The data structure represented by your json is not flat. Therefore, it cannot be represented as a single DataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@event` property must be of type `List<List<Event>>`.

```
public class MyRootObject
{
    public List<List<Event>> @event { get; set; }
}
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BetOffer> BetOffers { get; set; }
}
public class BetOffer
{
    public string BetType { get; set; }
    public List<BetPick> Picks { get; set; }
}
public class BetPick
{
    public string Pick { get; set; }
    public double Odds { get; set; }
}
```

Let's iterate through this structure. Since you used a `for` loop, I also made code on `for` loops (of course, this code can be greatly simplified).

```
for (int i = 0; i < root.@event.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < root.@event[i].Count; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + root.@event[i][j].Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + root.@event[i][j].Name);

        for (int k = 0; k < root.@event[i][j].BetOffers.Count; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BetType: " + root.@event[i][j].BetOffers[k].BetType);

            for (int l = 0; l < root.@event[i][j].BetOffers[k].Picks.Count; l++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(root.@event[i][j].BetOffers[k].Picks[l].Pick +
                    "  " + root.@event[i][j].BetOffers[k].Picks[l].Odds);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are *four* nested loops. A `DataTable` is a square matrix that can be traversed by *two* loops.

The data structure represented by your json is not flat. Therefore, it cannot be represented as a single `DataTable`.

Comment: Hi Alexander Petrov. Thanks very much.